# what code for One Page checkout in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to add One Page checkout in woo commerce code.
Please provide me the right code.
I use this code:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_to_checkout');

function woo_redirect_to_checkout() {
global $woocommerce;
$checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
return $checkout_url;
}
```

Comment: is it right or not??

Comment: this is quite right.

Comment: thanks, for more information visit here: http://khushwantyadav.com/one-page-checkout-in-woocommerce/